Calculating Fibonacci Sequence to 46 times or more in 8086 Assembly
I'm learning 8086 assembly through college course and i ran into a problem. I'm trying to calculate Fibonacci sequence to 46 places but 16-bits registers inside this processors can't handle large numbers. So i decided to use two registers for my calculation but at some point the code fails. can someone help me find and fix the problem? i'm using EMU8086 for simulating.
My current code:
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
FibArray dw 92 dup(0)

.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov word ptr FibArray[0], 0
mov word ptr FibArray[2], 0
mov word ptr FibArray[4], 1
mov word ptr FibArray[6], 0

mov cx, 44
mov si, 0
mov di, 4
lea bx, FibArray + 8

fib_loop:
mov ax, word ptr FibArray[si]
mov dx, word ptr FibArray[si+2]

add ax, word ptr FibArray[di]
adc dx, word ptr FibArray[di+2]

mov word ptr [bx], ax
mov word ptr [bx+2], dx

add si, 4
add di, 4
add bx, 4

loop fib_loop

mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
main endp
end main

This is my current output(unsigned):

0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 13, 0, 21, 0, 34, 0, 55, 0,
89, 0, 144, 0, 233, 0, 377, 0, 610, 0, 987, 0, 1597, 0, 2584, 0, 4181,
0, 6765, 0, 10946, 0, 17711, 0, 28657, 0, 46368, 0, 9489, 1, 55857, 1,
65346, 2, 55667, 4, 55477, 7, 45608, 12, 35549, 20, 15621, 33, 51170,
53, 1255, 87, 52425, 140, 53680, 227, 40569, 368, 28713, 596, 3746,
965, 32459, 1561, 36205, 2526, 3128, 4088, 39333, 6614, 42461, 10702,
16258, 17317


What were you expecting? It appears you're outputting the results as pairs of 16-bit integers, rather than as 32-bit integers.

@NateEldredge the problem is that after 24th element (0, 46368) the values are wrong. is there any way to display them correctly?

Your code does not include any printing. Make sure you post the code you are running as a [mcve]. Also it's confusing to use 3 indices when you could just use a single one with the appropriate offsets.

Displaying numbers with DOS includes a 32-bit printing function.

@PeterCordes i'm not directly printing the final values. i'm checking the vars section in EMU8086.

Note that 9489, 1 is the correct result when interpreted in low, high order (as all the other items are in this order too). That is 9489 + 1 * 65536 = 75025 = 46368 + 28657

@Jester thank you so much.

So then the question is whether EMU8086 can be set to dump memory as 32 bit values. If not then you'll have to write code to print it yourself.

Does it help to declare your output as FibArray dd 46 dup(0)?  If EMU8086 takes into account the declared element-size. Then your stores need word ptr to override the 32-bit size implied by dd.

If you look at pairs of words in hex, you'll get the same hex digits whether you look one, two, or four bytes at a time, just with gaps or not.  16 is a power of 2 so each digit depends only on 4 bits of the output.  But 10 isn't a power of 2; each decimal digit depends on all the bits of the whole number, so it depends whether you (or EMU8086's debugger) treat it as two 16-bit halves or one 32-bit whole.  e.g. the low decimal digit is x % 10.  And e.g. the low bit of the top half has a place-value of 1<<16 = 65536 so it being set or not affects all the decimal digits below that.

Anyway, we could reopen this question once you [edit] it with an actual description of where that output comes from, the fact that it's from EMU8086 itself, not some other code that prints the array.  For now it should stay closed as lacking important details.
